# How to get the integral representation of $f'$ from that of $f$? (Cauchy's Integral Formula)

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I know that if $f$ is holomorphic on an open set $\Omega$ containing a circle $C$ and it's interior, then for any $z_0$ in the interior of $C$ we have

$$f(z_0) = \dfrac {1}{2 \pi i} \int_{C} \dfrac {f(w)}{w-z}dw$$

where $C$ has positive orientation. If we compute the difference quotient, it comes out to

$$f'(z_0) = \dfrac {1}{2 \pi i}  \lim_{h \to 0} \int_C \dfrac {f(w)}{(w-z_0)(w-z_0 - h)}dw$$

Obviously I would like to interchange the limit and the integral. I guess that would be possible by bringing in some fancier theorems, but is there a way to get around this with just the basics and get to

$$f'(z_0) =\dfrac {1}{2 \pi i} \int_C \dfrac {f(w)}{(w-z_0)^2}dw$$

Comment: I believe that you either need to know that you can swap the limit and the integral there, or alternatively that an absolutely convergent power series can be integrated termwise.

Comment: @MisterRiemann Hmm I do know that there are some tricks that you can do (on a case by case basis I guess) to get around having to interchange the limit and integral. I am reading Complex Analysis by Stein and Shakarchi; in the proof of the Cauchy integral formula, if you go the straightforward way, it does come down to a situation like this where you have to interchange the limit and the integral; however, what they do is they split the integrand into two pieces; one that goes to $0$ as "h" goes to zero, and one which has an antiderivative. I don't see how to use that trick here though.

Comment: Interesting, I'm not aware of any such tricks for this result. Let's wait and see!

Comment: Try using the Dominated Convergence Theorem

Comment: Have you covered the Taylor series representation of holomorphic functions?

Comment: @zhw. In the book I am using, the Taylor representation is soon after this proof. Actually now I am worried about the book (Stein & Shakarchi Complex Analysis). They actually have a proof of what I'm asking in the question. I didn't read it on purpose until I posted the question, but now that I have read it, I believe they are switching the limit with the integral without justification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\epsilon=\min\limits_{w\in C}|w-z_0|>0$ and $|h|<\frac{\epsilon}2$ so that $|w-z_0-h|>\frac{\epsilon}2$ for all $w\in C$. We have
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{f(z_0+h)-f(z_0)}{h}-\frac1{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{f(w)}{(w-z_0)^2} dw&=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{f(w)}{w-z_0}\left(\frac{1}{w-z_0-h}-\frac1{w-z_0}\right) dw\\&=\frac{h}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{f(w)dw}{(w-z_0)^2(w-z_0-h)} 
\end{align*}$$, and
$$\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{f(z_0+h)-f(z_0)}{h}-\frac1{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{f(w)}{(w-z_0)^2} dw\right|&\le \frac{|h|}{2\pi}\cdot \int_C \frac{\max_{w\in C}|f(w)|}{\epsilon^3/2}\ |dw|\\&\le \frac{\text{len}(C)}{\pi} \frac{\max_{w\in C}|f(w)|}{\epsilon^3}\cdot |h|.
\end{align*}$$ If we let $|h|\to 0$, it follows that
$$
\lim_{h\to 0}\left|\frac{f(z_0+h)-f(z_0)}{h}-\frac1{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{f(w)}{(w-z_0)^2} dw\right|=0
$$, or equivalently,
$$
f'(z_0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(z_0+h)-f(z_0)}{h}=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{f(w)}{(w-z_0)^2} dw.
$$